# Visual Studio 2017 Slow File Operations (delete, rename, create)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

While using Visual Studio 2017 (latest release) as of April 13, when I try to delete or rename a file within vs.net it takes roughly 2-4 minutes to delete the file.  Visual Studio hangs while this file operation is occurring. This does not happen in previously releases of Visual Studio.

Comment: Microsoft has a Connect site to collect Visual Studio bug reports, and also you can report such from inside Visual Studio.

Comment: Questions like this need to document the installed anti-malware product.

Comment: Our IT staff use sophos virus protection

Answer (score 0):

It's normally happens when long list of library packages are there that you never touch when development.

bower components, node_modules would be possible.

Answer (score -2):

The best option for me is to disable source control

Settings -> Source Control -> Nothing.

And use an other source control like smartGit.